# App rejected due to Advertising Identifier (IDFA)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

My application was rejected due to the following reasons:

> You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have
>   contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier,
>   and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising
>   Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user
>   resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine,
>   correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly,
>   the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the
>   reset Advertising Identifier." Note: iAd does not use the `AdSupport.framework`, `ASIdentifierManager`, or the Advertising Identifier.
>   Therefore they are not required for iAd implementations and should not
>   be included in your app for iAd support.  If your app is serving ads,
>   please:
>   - Ensure that you have tested your app on a device, not just the simulator, and that you have removed all previous versions of your app
>   prior to testing
>   - Provide us the steps to locate ads in your app If your app does not serve ads, please check your code - including any third-party
>   libraries - to remove any instances of: class: `ASIdentifierManager`
>   selector: `advertisingIdentifier` framework: `AdSupport.framework`

I have tested my app on a device and simulator and it does show *You're Connected to iAd* test banners. It doesn't let me log into the iAd Workbench so maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Have you signed all the necessary iAd contracts?

Comment: I cannot sign into iAd Workbench, so if it's in iAd Workbench, I didn't.

Comment: iAd workbench is for putting ads on the iAd network, not for showing ads in your app.

Comment: Contracts are on iTunes connect in contracts, tax & banking.

Comment: Yes, I've signed that!

Comment: Did you tell apple where to locate your ads in your app?

Comment: Did you answer "Yes" to the question does your app using the advertising identifier when you submitted your app?  If you only use iAd then you should answer "No" to this question as iAd does not use the advertising identifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If iAd is the only advertising network you're using you need to answer **No** to the following question when submitting your application to the App Store:

> Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?

Also, make sure your project does not import the `AdSupport.framework`. iAd does not use the `AdSupport.framework`, `ASIdentifierManager`, or the Advertising Identifier so they are not required and should not be included in your application.