# iAd uses IDFA but doesn't support functionality and is causing app rejection

Tags: ios, iad, idfa

I have completed an app that uses iAd banner ads from Apple. When I submitted it, it was rejected for using the Advertising Identifier but not including ad functionality. This is an update for my app, and I don't think the code is wrong because its the code I use in another one of my apps that has ads.

What does this mean, and how to fix it? I really don't want to submit it and be rejected again.

Comment: Do ads appear when you run the app is test?

Comment: If you use *only* iAd then you must answer "No" when asked if your app uses the advertising identifier.  iAd does not use the advertising identifier.  If you answered "no" and are still getting a rejection then you should scan any 3rd party frameworks to make sure they aren't using it

Comment: Check my answer here: [App rejected due to Advertising Identifier (IDFA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598360/app-rejected-due-to-advertising-identifier-idfa)

Comment: I'm using only iAd but I am using social frameworks to share scores. My iAd does work-what kind of answer is for this?